# Jetty http server : How to pass VM arguments to Jetty (configure timezone)?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I want to specify the timezone for our embedded jetty server.

Trying to avoid this:

`java -Duser.timezone=UTC.`

Jetty is currently configured like this:

```
public Server jettyServerConfig() {
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new Server();
        .
        .
    server.setAttribute("-Duser.timezone", "UTC");//doesn't work
    server.setAttribute("user.timezone", "UTC");//doesn't work
    return server;
}

public HttpServer jettyServer() {
    return new JettyHttpServer(jettyServerConfig(), true);
}
```

How should I go about to pass VM arguments to JETTY?

Any advice appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone zone)` method to change the time zone programmatically for the JVM, e.g.:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```